# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, database-connection

Can someone please tell me why this doesnt work, when I tried to switch my old sql to sqli:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `product_category`";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect) or die("could not perform query: " . mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i=0; $i < $num_rows; $i++)
{
    $ID = mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
    $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
    $description = mysql_result($result,$i,"description");
```

to:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM `product_category`");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die("could not perform query");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for ($i=0; $i < $num_rows; $i++)
{
    $ID = mysqli_result($result, "ID");
    $name = mysqli_result($result,$i,"name");
    $description = mysqli_result($result,$i,"description");`
```

it keeps giving me an error of: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()"

Comment: Where's your call to `mysqli_error()`? You need to pass the connection variable into it as a parameter.

Comment: There is no `mysqli_result()` function. You could supply your own, to emulate the behavior of the `mysql_result()` function, but you don't really want to do that. Better to go with the newer model, and just use a call to the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function. And there's no need to get the count of rows, and a for loop.  Just use a while loop. The `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function will return FALSE when there are no more rows to fetch, exiting you from the loop. See the answer from Marc B.

Comment: So annoying when you're using an open source project and they're only selecting one value from one column and you have to fix it because it's broken everywhere..... Damn you Salazar!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use this kind of code. It's highly inefficient. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $id = $row['ID'];
   $name = $row['name']; 
   etc..
}
```

One SINGLE database operation, rather than the 3+ you're trying to do.

Comment: +1. To actually answer the first question the OP posed, "tell me why this doesn't work"... the reason the code in the question doesn't work is that it makes calls to a non-existent `mysqli_result()` function. That function does not exist.

Comment: yep, because it was a moronic function in the mysql library to begin with.

Comment: Hey now! :) Some of us moronics just happen to like a moronic function we can use, widdout us havin's to understand all dem highfalutin hijinx dat happens behind da curtains. I just want my moronic field value! (i kid, i kid) (I have seen <twitch> an implementation of a `mysqli_result` function <shudder>).

Comment: Yes, excellent circumscription by another mysqli function. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_result')) {
  function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
    $res->data_seek($row);
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array();
    return $datarow[$field];
  }
}
```

You can create this function.

Comment: This is a helpful answer when you need to get old code up and running again. You can use [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to create the function only when it is needed.

Comment: Very good way to deal with older code which needs to be brought up to more modern mysqli standards but lack the rescription of code the very good and only working way Marc B has shown here.