# How to pass connection varible in other php document

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Help me with this code: I get this error.

Notice: Undefined variable: dbCon in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\general.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\general.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: dbCon in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\login.php(4): user_exists(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php on line 8

Main folder(name -> PHP) has **Index.php**:

```
    <?php 
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
?>
```

PHP folder has **Login.php**:

```
 <?php
include 'core/init.php';

if(user_exists('sudin') === true)
{
    echo 'exists';
}
?>
```

under php/core folder **init.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
?>
```

under php/core/database **connect.php:**

```
<?php
$dbCon=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','project_point');

?>
```

under php/core/functions **Users.php:**

```
<?php
function user_exists($username)
{
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT COUNT('Login_ID')FROM 'login' WHERE 'Username' = '$username'");
    return(mysqli_result($query,0)==1) ? true : false;
}
 ?>
```

under php/core/functions **general.php:**

```
<?php

function sanitize($data)
{
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon,$data);
}
?>[enter image description here][1]
```

Sorry for the messy way, here is the treeview:

[image]

Thankful for the help

Comment: `$dbCon` should be global

Comment: Thanks, that worked. What about the last error (Fatal error)..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

Firstly, you have a variable scope issue and you're also using the wrong [identifier qualifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) in your query being regular quotes:

So, remove the quotes for this:

```
SELECT COUNT('Login_ID')FROM 'login' WHERE 'Username'
             ^        ^      ^     ^       ^        ^ Remove those
```

or use ticks:

```
SELECT COUNT(`Login_ID`) FROM `login` WHERE `Username`
```

Checking for errors on it using `mysqli_error($dbCon)` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have thrown you something about it once it would have fired.

Make your connection global in your `user_exists()` function

```
global $dbCon;
```

Read up on both:

- Identifier qualifiers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-qualifiers.html
- Variable scope http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: OP's not paying attention here.

Comment: Whatever. This answer must be the same color as the background: white.

Comment: Calm down buddy, your time to shine will come.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Too many cooks in the kitchen *lol*. TBH, I've given up.

Comment: There there buddy, OP is just confused and doesn't know what to do.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Seems to be the case Charlotte. Thanks, cheers.

Comment: I think no one noticed FATAL error. Please solve it. mysqli_result() and mysql_result() both are giving the same error..

Comment: @Sudi ah yes... you're right. You need to replace that `mysqli_result()` with another function. See this answer for an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/17707384/ or simply use `mysqli_error($dbCon)` in its place if the goal is to check if the query failed or not. Also consult http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: Apparently, forgot to upvote :) Tracking down old answers.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The connection variable is not defined in the function scope. The hotfix is to add it with the "global" construct.

```
function user_exists($username)
{
global $dbCon;
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. What about the last error (Fatal error)..?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use a local variable $dbCon inside the function user_exists.

you can just change that variable to be global

ex:

under php/core/database connect.php:

```
<?php
global $dbCon;
$dbCon=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','project_point');

?>
```

under php/core/functions Users.php:

```
<?php
function user_exists($username)
{
    global $dbCon;
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT COUNT('Login_ID')FROM 'login' WHERE 'Username' = '$username'");
    return(mysqli_result($query,0)==1) ? true : false;
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$dbCon` is not defined in the scope of any function.
You could do 3 things:

```
function user_exists($username){
  $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbCon'] ... 

function user_exists($username){
  global $dbCon;
  $query = mysqli_query($dbCon ...
```

However, using globals in functions like this is usually a bad coding style.
I would recommend doing something like the following:

```
function getconn(){
  static $conn;
  if(!isset($conn)){
    $conn = new mysqli_connect(...);
  } 

  return $conn;
}

function user_exists($username){
  $query = mysqli_query(getconn() ...
```

I was just about to add the issues with your SQL syntax, but Fred beat me to it. I think you want backticks ` instead, not `'`.

Comment: Great help. what about the Fatal error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\login.php(4): user_exists(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php on line 8

Comment: There is no such function in mysqli, however you could [add](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20961496/4982088) the function that works like the old mysql_result().

Comment: Same for that also: Call to undefined function mysql_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\login.php(4): user_exists('sudin') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\Users.php on line 9