# Fatal error showing

Tags: php-7, php-5.3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in /home/prasanth/projects/ishen1/index.php:49 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown 
 how to slove this

Answer (score -1):

according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17707384/8284461 that function is inefficient, you can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead. for example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $id = $row['ID'];
   $name = $row['name']; 
   etc..
}
```

Comment: <?php

//require_once("dbcontroller.php");

$con=require_once("dbcontroller.php");


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


$document="select max(id) from Register";
$res=mysqli_query($document);
$id=mysqli_result($res,$row=0,$col=0);
$id++;
$n=$_FILES['document']['name'];
$ext=strrchr($n,".");
$fname="$id$ext";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['documnet']['tmp_name'],"photo/$fname");




?>